# Regular directed graphs with short paths

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-designs, directed-graphs

For given $n$ and $k$, I am looking for a directed graph with $n$ vertices such that:

- All vertices have in- and out-degree $2$.
- For all vertices $v$ and $w$, the (directed) distance from $v$ to $w$ is at most $k$.

When $n=2^k$, there is an easy construction. On the other hand, $n<2^{k+1}$ is necessary from the out-degree restriction.

My question is: For which $n$ and $k$ do such digraphs exist?

The generalization to other degrees than $2$ may be of additional interest.

[EDIT]

Some clarification in response to a comment:

A solution for $n$ and $k$ is always a solution for all larger $k'$ as well. So I could rephrase the question as follows: Given $n$, what is the smallest $k$ such that a digraph as above exists. The condition $n<2^{k+1}$ gives a lower bound, and in case $n$ is a power of $2$ I have a matching upper bound: 
Number the vertices from $0$ to $n-1$ and let the edges from vertex $i$ go to $2i\mod n$ and $(2i+1)\mod n$. 
If $2^k < n < 2^{k+1}$, the same construction can be used to achieve an upper bound of $k+1$, which leaves a gap of $1$ to the lower bound.

Comment: It seems like you've nailed down the least possible value of $k$ to $\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$. Is your question whether this is achievable for all $n$? Or do you want to know a *greatest* possible value of $k$ for a given $n$? Do you also want to find constructions for every value of $k$ between the smallest and greatest possible value? (Do you care about the technicality where a graph that works for $n$ and $k$ also works for $n$ and $k+1$?)

Comment: So true. My mistake.

Comment: An other solution when $n=2^k$ is [de Brujin graph $B(2,k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517930/solving-an-eulerian-trail-in-a-digraph).

Comment: @AlexRavsky: The de Bruijn graph as defined in your linked question is the same as mine if you identify the vector $x$ with $\sum_i2^{n-i}x_i$.