# Solving an Eulerian trail in a digraph

Tags: graph-theory

How would you go about solving this?

Let's define a digraph $D_n$ with the following ruleset: $n ∈ N, n ≥ 2$. The vertices of $D_n$ are binary vectors with n dimensions: $x ∈ \{0, 1\}^n$

$∀x, y ∈ \{0, 1\}^n$, $xy$ is an arc in $D_n$ $⇔ (x_2, . . . , x_n) = (y_1, . . . , y_{n−1}).$

It's worth noting that in $D_n$ every vertex has exactly two successors: $ [ (x_2, . . . , x_n, 0),
(x_2, . . . , x_n, 1) ] $ and exactly two predecessors: $ [ (0, x_1, . . . , x_{n−1}), (1, x_1, . . . , x_{n−1}) ]$

How would you solve the following:

A. Make a pictorial representation of $D_3$

B. Prove that $D_n$ is a tournament for any $n ≥ 2$ and show that $D_n$ allows for a closed eulerian trail

C. Assume $L(D_n)$ is a line-digraph associated to $D_n$ (The vertices of $L(D_n)$ are the arcs of $D_n$). Show that $L(D_n)$ $∼= D_{n+1}$. Deduce that $D_n$ allows for a hamiltonian circuit, $∀n ≥ 3$

Comment: How far have you gotten on your own? I refuse to believe that you're stuck on the "draw a picture" step.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I did indeed get past A but that's about it, I didn't mention it but I figured I would include it so I could compare my version to the answer, given the answer would include A.

Comment: Well, it's generally helpful to say something like "I solved A, but then I got stuck on B, because I don't know what a closed Eulerian trail is / don't remember the condition / disagree that the graph is a tournament / etc." It's good to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The graph $D_n$ is de Brujin graph $B(2,n)$. See references [W1; W2 Construction; CZ, Section 3.2, p. 76-79] for  properties and pictures of these graphs. In particular, Theorem 3.6 in [CZ] states that for every two integers $k, n \ge 2$ the de Bruijn digraph $B(k, n)$ is Eulerian,
because it is connected and the outdegree and indegree of every its vertex $k$. **None** of the graphs $B(k, n)$ is a tournament because each of them has loops.

References

[W1] Wikipedia *[De Bruijn graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph)*.

[W2] Wikipedia *[De Bruijn sequence. Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction)*.

[CZ] Gary Chartrand, Ping Zhang *[Chromatic Graph Theory](http://web.xidian.edu.cn/zhangxin/files/20150825_221833.pdf)*,  CRC Press, 2009.